# What is the probability that the sequence “broken, good, good, broken, good” occurs in the next $5$ bottles?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a probability problem. I think I know how to solve $A$, but $B$ is still a mystery to me. If anyone could help me I appreciate a lot.

> Return bottles are constantly returned to the lemonade factory. There is a probability of $18\%$ of a bottle to be broken. This probably occurs independently.
>
> A) what is the probability that the sequence “broken, good, good, broken, good” occurs in the next $5$ bottles?
>
> B) what is the probability of the $10$ first bottles of the next $147$ bottles being good?

For $A$ I think is $0.18\times(1-0.18)\times(1-0.18)\times0.18\times(1-0.18)$. And, for $B$, it seems a negative binomial probability, but I am not sure.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer for A is correct. For B, we can use the binomial probability formula, because each event is independent:

$Pr(X=x)=\binom{n}{x} \times p^x \times (1-p)^{n-x}$

Where we solve for $Pr(X=10)$, knowing $p=(1-0.18)$, and $n=10$

$Pr(X=10)=\binom{10}{10} \times 0.82^{10} \times (1-0.82)^{10-10}$

$=1 \times 0.82^{10} \times 1$

$=0.82^{10}$

Alternatively, and much quicker, we can just compute $0.82^{10}$, because the only possible combination for $10$ successes in $10$ trials is $10$ consequetive successes.

Answer (score 5):

A) is correct

B) simply $0.82^{10}$. What happens in the next 137 bottles is not relevant